# SharePoint 2016 Search Schema - An unknown error occurred

Tags: search, 2016, sharepoint-server

We have an on-premises SharePoint 2016 farm consisting of 3 servers (application&search+wfe+database). We recently found that the enterprise search wasn't working. When looked at the crawl logs under the Search Service Application, the following error was reported and the crawl wasn't working:

*Content Processing Pipeline Failed to Process the Item*

There were comments on Internet suggesting that this could be due to an issue with Manged Matadata Property Mappings, but when click on the Search Schema in Search Administration, it displays the following error without showing the Managed Properties.

*An unknown error occurred.*

We've tried restarting the Search Host Service and Time Service, but it didn't help.

Any assistance with resolving the issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the ULS logs. Check the Search Databases health. It could be any number of things, but the ULS is the place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to re-produce the error in my lab environment by installing The February CU.  I've provided the error messages from the ULS logs below for others benefit. Installing the latest update didn't resolve the issue and eventually, I ended up submitting a ticket to Microsoft. The solution was to build a new Search Application. The errors <br/> earchServiceApplication::QueryManagedProperties--Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException <br /> failed propertyName PopulateTimeInterval exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Yep, sadly the CU can lead to these problems.